# Creating Kubernetes service that reference external service by multiple ip addresses

Tags: kubernetes, dns

Is there a way in Kubernetes to create a service for an external service that should return multiple IP addresses? Currently I am hacking around this by creating an A record in my public DNS provider (route53) and then in Kubernetes creating a service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: rabbitmq
  labels:
    app: rabbitmq
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: rabbitmq.mydomainhere.dev
```

Is there a way to create a service natively in Kubernetes that returns a fixed set of IP addresses that are not managed inside of the Kubernetes cluster without creating a public DNS record and using `externalName`?

Comment: Are you looking for [Services without selectors](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#services-without-selectors), manually creating an `Endpoints` object rather than binding a service to specific pods?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can create a headless service without selectors and set clusterIP to None, then create an endpoint manually to have all your IPs set in the endpoint. You can take a look at the following example.

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: my-es
spec:
  clusterIP: None

---
kind: Endpoints
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: my-es
subsets:
  - addresses:
      - ip: 172.22.111.250
      - ip: 172.22.149.230
    ports:
      - port: 9200
```

nslookup output from one Pod

```
root@curl-66bdcf564-8m6h7:/ ]$ nslookup my-es
Server:    169.254.25.10
Address 1: 169.254.25.10

Name:      my-es
Address 1: 172.22.111.250 172-22-111-250.my-es.default.svc.cluster.local
Address 2: 172.22.149.230 172-22-149-230.my-es.default.svc.cluster.local
```

Comment: Awesome thanks. What is the point of specifying the port `9200` in both the service and endpoint in your example if we just want to expose a DNS entry?

Comment: @Justin You don't need to specify the port if you just want to expose a DNS entry. The ports specified in Endpoint is used for the SRV records. Please ignore the ports in service, it doesn't make any sense if you don't use clusterIp. I will remove it from the original post

Answer (score 2):

An ExternalIP service uses an IP address from the predefined pool of external IP addresses routed to the cluster’s nodes. These external IP addresses are not managed by Kubernetes; they  are the responsibility of the cluster administrator.

You can create a headless service without selectors and set clusterIP to None, then create an endpoint manually to have all your IPs set in the endpoint. You can take a look at the following example.

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: my-es
spec:
  clusterIP: None

---
kind: Endpoints
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: my-es
subsets:
  - addresses:
      - ip: 172.22.111.250
      - ip: 172.22.149.230
    ports:
      - port: 9200
```

nslookup output from one Pod

```
root@curl-66bdcf564-8m6h7:/ ]$ nslookup my-es
Server:    169.254.25.10
Address 1: 169.254.25.10

Name:      my-es
Address 1: 172.22.111.250 172-22-111-250.my-es.default.svc.cluster.local
Address 2: 172.22.149.230 172-22-149-230.my-es.default.svc.cluster.local
```

Documentation: [service-selectors](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#services-without-selectors).
Useful article: [exposing-pods](https://www.stratoscale.com/blog/kubernetes/kubernetes-exposing-pods-service/).