# How can k8s be aware of service running on host?

Tags: kubernetes

I am running Cockpit on my host, its running as systemd service, at the same time I am using microk8s (single node k8s).

I dont need reverse proxy to Cockpit web ui, but I need something like external service/endpoint k8s object mapping, .. to be k8s aware of that service.

- k8s should not allow to create another nodePort service with same port ( k8s layer, it should not collide on OS layer )
- k8s should handle rules for that service in iptables.

Btw: Cockpit must be running as standalone application directly on host.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Do you mean accessing the external service inside k8s cluster? It that is the case, you will need to create a headless service. Take a look at my answer in the following link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57618606/creating-kubernetes-service-that-reference-external-service-by-multiple-ip-addre/57618703#57618703

Comment: Not so exactly. Lets imagine that I will start a web service on 6060/tcp port. On the same host I will try to publish service with NodePort 6060/tcp, this will not happend, there will be port collision. k8s needs to be aware open 6060/tcp port on the host. So I though that mapping it to external service will handle this problem.

Comment: So you are trying to reserve the external service port, in the meantime, you also need to access Cockpit via the K8S IP and NodePort, am I correct? If it is the case, you can create a service for Cockpit without selector and set the type to NodePort with value 6060/tcp